# How do I alter content on Scribd?

Tags: scribd

I have Scribd files on my website: http://www.wellbeingbydesign.com/main/?cat=7

Since my webmaster got sick, I don't know how to get into these Scribd files to edit them.

Thanks,

Catherine

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with it, but I think you need to login to scribd.com and upload/edit your documents.  You of course will need your login.  If you don't have that you might just be able to create a new account, upload, and then change your web app to point to the new location.